# State is changed, but component is not refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am changing the state and I can see in the `console.log` the new state, however, the `TextArea` does not show the new state, but only when its first displayed.

Here is my implementation:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {TextArea} from "semantic-ui-react";

class Output extends Component {

    static myInstance = null;
    state = { keys:[] }

    updateState(){
        // this method is called from outside.. 
        this.setState({ keys:this.state.keys.push(0) });
        // I can see that keys are getting increase
        console.log(this.state.keys);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TextArea value={this.state.keys.length} />

        );
    }
}
```

`TextArea` will keep showing `0`, although the length of `state.keys` increases..

Any idea?

Comment: Where do you call the updateState method?

Comment: did you try to push to a new variable and do it? for example, const tempKeys = this.state.keys and then tempKeys.push(0) and then this.setState({ keys: tempKeys });...do tell me if it works and i also see your updateState is unused

Answer (score 3):

Never mutate the state.
To update the state, use this syntax:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  keys: [...prevState.keys, newItem]
}))
```

Comment: `this.setState({keys: [...this.state.case, newItem]})` will also do the job. The main point is you should not mutate `keys` prop, rather assign new array to it. Generally, the problem may happen because `TextArea` is `React.PureComponent`

Answer (score 0):

you dont call your `updateState` function to update your state , it just exists over there, for pushing `0` to your state in order to reRender your component with new state, you can call your method in componentDidMount like below:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.updateState()
}
```

this will excute your `updateState` function immediately after component mounts into the dom.

Comment: '// this method is called from outside.. '

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example

Firstly you should call your function to update the state

[Example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AntonWebDev2012/b1uzjht6/3/)

```
class Output extends React.Component {

 static myInstance = null;
 state = { keys:[] }

 componentDidMount(){
    this.updateState();
 }

 updateState() {
    const newKeys = [...this.state.keys,0]
  this.setState({ keys:newKeys });
 }
 onTextareaChange(){}

 render() {
  return (
    <textarea value={this.state.keys.length} onChange= {this.onTextareaChange} />
  );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Output />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```